# Writing List into JObject

Tags: windows-phone-8, json.net

I'm trying to create a JObject of the following format

```
{history_dates: 
     [
       {start_date: "2014-03-02" status: "Added" end_date: "2014-03-02"},
       {start_date: "2014-04-02" status: "Added" end_date: "2014-04-02"},
       {start_date: "2014-05-02" status: "Deleted" end_date: "2014-05-02"}
     ]}
```

The moment it tried to add d to JChild, it crashes!

```
        JObject jChild = new JObject();
        for (int i = 0; i < m_iHistCount; i++)
        {
            string endDate = "";
            if (m_dtEndDate[i] != GetDefaultDate())
            {
                endDate = m_dtEndDate[i].ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            }
            var d = new { start_date = m_dtHistory[i].Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), status = (SYNC_STATUS)histDtSyncStatus[i], end_date = endDate };
            jChild.Add(d);
        }
```

Is it not the right way??

Comment: This does not seem like valid Json. Can you confirm it this is what you get in response?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you tried the wrong way. Check following example :

```
//declare JArray to store history_dates value
JArray historyDates = new JArray();
for (int i = 0; i < m_iHistCount; i++)
{
    string endDate = "";
    if (m_dtEndDate[i] != GetDefaultDate())
    {
        endDate = m_dtEndDate[i].ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }
    var d = string.Format("{{ \"start_date\" = \"{0}\", \"status\" = \"{1}\", \"end_date\" = \"{2}\"}}",
                                  m_dtHistory[i].Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), 
                                  (SYNC_STATUS)histDtSyncStatus[i],
                                  endDate);
    historyDates.Add(d);
}

JObject root = new JObject();
//add property history_dates and assign above mentioned JArray as the property value
root.Add("history_dates", historyDates);
```

you can also construct anonymous object then serialize it to string as follow :

```
var d = new { start_date = m_dtHistory[i].Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), status = (SYNC_STATUS)histDtSyncStatus[i], end_date = endDate };
historyDates.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d));
```

but it will be more efficient to construct Json string in the first place